# How to grant Java-Programm Admin privileges programmatically,so it does not ask for them everytime

Tags: java, windows, registrykey

I'm currently working on a small game, which I want to start automatically when booting the PC/logging into my User account. I used the WinRegistry Library to write a Key into the Current_User and the Local_Machine. Here is the part of the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    new MainFrame().run();
    String value = "\""+System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\Game.exe\"";
    try {
        WinRegistry.writeStringValue(WinRegistry.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", "Game", value);
        WinRegistry.writeStringValue(WinRegistry.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", "Game", value);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

As you can see, for the Value I build a String around the Directory from where the program has been started. Originally, I wanted to only start the .jar file, but because of missing Administration rights, the program does not start, so I wrapped my .jar file in a .exe file and now I'm getting asked for permission and it seems to work. But now I encountered two more problems.

First, the Key seems only to be set at the Current_User, but never in Local_Machine, I tried and checked multiple times, but it never appears in the Local_Machine. 
However, second, the only key that is now set in Current_User seems to work just fine. When I log in, the programme starts but asks me for permission first. It's not a lot to do, 2 buttons and it is done, I know, but after starting the PC a hundred times, it gets a pain in the ass. So if anyone knows how I can achieve, so that I only have to grant the program the Admin privileges once, that would be really great.

Thanks for your help and have a nice day, If I missed something important, please don't hesitate to tell me. :)

Comment: Why not use the Task Scheduler to launch your application upon logon?

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, thanks, I will look further into this. :)